# BASIC Program giving unexpected text output

Tags: calculator, basic

EDIT: Yes, this is BASIC for the TI-84. I mistakenly believed all BASIC programs were alike.

I am working on a program for turning decimal hours into hours and minutes (part of an E6B emulator) but I'm having issues with it returning stuff like "5 HHOURS 7 MMINUTES" with a second letter at the beginning. I believe it's an issue with the variable being parsed as text, but I'm unable to solve this problem

````
1  int(X)→H 
2  round(60(X-H),0)→M
3  ClrHome
4  If H=1
5  Output(3,1,"1 HOUR")
6  5+5→K     [This is just to add an extra line to the IF statement.]
7  If H<1
8  Goto 1
9  Output(3,4,"HOURS")
10 Output(3,1,H)
11 Lbl 1
12 If M=1
13 Output(3,10,"1 MINUTE")
14 If M<1
15 Goto 2
16 Output(3,13,"MINUTES") 
17 Output(3,10,M)
18 Lbl 2
19 Pause "PRESS ENTER TO EXIT"
20 ClrHome ```
````

Comment: Since every BASIC language is slightly different, it would help if we knew which BASIC language this was...

Comment: It appears to be TI-BASIC, as in the kind the TI graphing calculators used (probably still do, but I don't know that).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing lines 9 and 16 like this:

```
9  Output(3,3,"HOURS")

16 Output(3,12,"MINUTES")
```

You will probably also need to add two more IF statements to your code to check if H < 10 and if M < 10 and account for two digit values

Comment: Wow, I'm really surprised that changing the position of the text also altered the text. Could you explain what my mistake was?
And yes, two-digit values will be an issue with the new code, is there a solution to this that will still fix the issue?

Comment: I think that at some point Lines 5 and 13 were executed - note that both write a single digit value, than a single space, and then HOUR & MINUTE. Later, when lines 9 and 16 are executed, the digit is overwritten and the col position for the strings allows for two spaces - the extra M and H are there from lines 5/13 and never gets overwritten.